# Instant messaging in coenameone

Tags: xmpp, codenameone, instant-messaging

I am developing codenameone application. It's working fine. but I need to implement Instant messagins system in my app.

Is this possible to do instant messaging system?

Is there any sdk in codenameone?

Answer (score 1):

This sample is a bit flawed but it should provide you a base guideline on how to accomplish IM in Codename One: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-1.html

There are a few apps that implemented IM in Codename One specifically https://www.codenameone.com/blog/featured-app-jat-communication.html